# How to disable "Download scanning protection" of new Chrome-17?

Tags: google-chrome, security, privacy

In recent update of Google Chrome internet browser (in stable channel), there is a new security/privacy option:

http://chrome.blogspot.com/2012/02/faster-browsing-safer-downloading.html

> In addition to checking a list of known bad files, Chrome also does checks on executable files (like ".exe" and ".msi" files). If the executable doesn't match a whitelist, Chrome checks with Google for more information, such as whether the website you're accessing hosts a high number of malicious downloads.

According to [more detail link](http://blog.chromium.org/2012/01/all-about-safe-browsing.html)

> If a file isn’t from a known source, Chrome sends the URL and IP of the host and other meta data, such as the file’s hash and binary size, to Google.

What if I want google not to know which executable files are downloaded by me and from?

*How can I disable* sending to google URLs and hashes of .exe and .msi downloaded?

Comment: Probably part of "enable phishing and malware protection" in settings. Chrome is headed toward being just another bloated browser, so sad.

Comment: Also see this...http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-bugs/browse_thread/thread/8963b69830d8de3b

Comment: As long as I can opt-out, I'm cool. Chrome is getting bloated a bit, but it's still a good browser.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Within the blog post you linked to, there is a [a link](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=99020) that explains how to disable the 'safe browsing' features.

> Turn off phishing & malware warnings
>
> The following steps will turn of phishing and malware warnings, as
> well as download warnings.
>
> - In the top-right corner of the browser window, click the Chrome menu    Chrome menu.
> - Select Settings.
> - Click Show advanced settings.
> - Under "Privacy," uncheck the box "Protect you and your device from dangerous sites"

#### 2019-Jan:

Advanced > Privacy and security > Safe Browsing

[image: 2019 January]

#### 2020-Jun:

Privacy and security > More > Safe Browsing

[image: 2020 June]

You could turn it back on after you download what you know is safe.

Comment: yes, but this page says nothing about "download scanning", so I think, it is not for disabling "download scanning" and sending url to google.

Comment: in the page i linked to above, follow the instructions under "Disable phishing and malware detection".

Comment: will it disable downloads checking too? How can you prove?

Comment: presumably so. your second question is ambiguous.

Comment: You can choose to keep individual files by clicking "recover malicious file" in the downloads list after they are blocked. I would do that on a case-by-case basis rather than disabling protection completely. I don't think disabling security settings is the greatest advice, even if it is in a Google blog post.

Comment: Google keeps finding ways to creatively block people from downloading the files they need. To get around this fake message, use the three vertical dots on Chrome in the top right of the window. Then click "downloads". On that list is a hidden button to allow you to keep the file anyway.

Answer (score 12):

An additional option is available. If you've downloaded a file and Chrome has blocked it, and you'd like to keep the file without disabling malware and phishing protection altogether, you can keep the file like so:

1. Download the file and let Chrome "block" it. If you are directed to a "site ahead contains harmful programs" page, click "details" then "visit the site".
2. After chrome displays the warning message in the download bar, click "show all downloads", or choose "downloads" from the menu, or press "ctrl+j" (on Windows at least).
3. The file will be in the download list. Click "recover malicious file". Then it will get that file.

This way you can keep your security settings but still make a decision about an individual file, which is generally the safer way to go instead of disabling the protection completely just for one or two files.

Comment: The question was about: how to stop Google from spying on my downloads. Your solution is good for unblocking files, but not for stopping the spy functionality.

Comment: Great solution for one-off downloads.

Comment: Is there a way to do it permanently? It looks like Chrome removed the checkbox from the other answers.

Comment: @G Well, you could use a different browser, I suppose, heh.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a fix.
Go to the icon that has 3 horizontal lines in the top right corner, right under the X -> go to stting near the bottom -> scroll down and click "show advanced setting" -> under the privacy section, uncheck the 5th box that says "enable fishing and malware protection"

Comment: 'fishing' lol...

Comment: That completely [disables *all protection*, not just file scanning](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2507056/security0/chrome-tips-users-to-dangerous-windows-downloads.html). (On the other hand, the URL scanning works the same; it tells Google about every site you visit to check if Google thinks it is a bad site or not).