# Why does saving a web page to disk take several seconds? Everything should already be loaded in memory/cache

Tags: google-chrome, memory, save-as

I sometimes save websites to disk for reference when I'm surfing. This is often news articles but can be anything.

When I do this, it almost always takes a few seconds, and in Chrome browser, there is a counter in the bottom left of the screen counting from 0 to some number , such as   `3/32 B`

There is no explanation what this is doing or what B is (obviously not Bytes).

The thing I don't understand is why this takes time at all. Loading a page in the first place takes a few seconds, when the browser gets the images, runs various scripts and whatnot. But when this has been finished and the page is rendered, all those things should be in cache or memory already, and we're not talking many megabytes, so why does it generally take 3-4 seconds, and sometimes much longer, to save the page to disk?

Edit: I found a somewhat [related post](https://superuser.com/questions/422836/any-ideas-why-im-getting-a-delay-after-clicking-save-as-or-download-in-goog) about hard drive disk needing to start spinning, but that is not applicable in my case since I'm using SSD and it does most things 'instantly' for much larger amounts of data than is the case here.

Comment: What does your research show?

Comment: Actually ... depending on what has been loaded megabytes is actually possible. In addition it just takes time to write files to disk. It can't just write out the data structure it has in memory and even if it would your virus scanner might want to check it.