# Unable to download file from Chrome due to "Failed Network Error"

Tags: google-chrome, firewall, anti-virus

I've got a weird downloading issue on Chrome (Version 73.0.3683.103 (Official Build) (64-bit)).

Let's say the accessed website of **http://192.168.2.10** and the Windows 10 laptop IP of **192.168.1.xxx** with AVG antivirus installed

1. Able to access the website with any links belonging to the website.
2. When click to download the documents, got the "Failed Network Error".
3. Open chrome://downloads and resume the failed download, the download progress showed the file size (xxxKB) and ended up with "Failed Network Error".

Troubleshoot

1. Tried to turn off the firewall and antivirus, it's still the same
2. Tried to access from Windows 10 laptop IP of **192.168.2.xxx** without antivirus installed, it's able to download

I suspect the issue related to antivirus/firewall but haven't found out how to resolve it.

Please help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Did you try to use another browser or disabling [Safe Browsing](https://superuser.com/a/389059/880618) on Chrome? It might help, normally those kinds of error it's an action from some antivirus.

Comment: Vague question. So you have webserver running at 192.168.2.10?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably your antivirus that is causing the problem.

You should begin with adding the website URL and the download path to AVG exceptions list.